# Is it possible to perform calculations inside a PHP associative array?

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I see that it is possible to calculate a value inside an associative array like this:

```
$testarray = array(
"x"=>2,
"y"=>5,
"z"=>(5*2);

 print_r($testarray); //Array ( [x] => 2 [y] => 5 [z] => 10 )
```

Is it possible to do it in a manner like this:

```
$testarray = array(
"x"=>2,
"y"=>5,
"z"=>x*y);
```

Comment: You can assign after declaring the array. `$a = ['x'=>2,'y'=>5]; $a['z'] = $a['x'] * $a['y'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You cannot access an array's elements before the array is defined.